# Unable to use symbols like "-" and "|" in my WordPress website its showing some character rather than "-" or "|" in the whole site

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, character-encoding, custom-wordpress-pages

[this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyVpQ.png)

I am working on a WordPress website but whenever I try to use symbols like "-" in place of this symbol it is displaying the symbol showed in above image.

what should I do to fix this problem?

[this is what I want it to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEXjS.png)

I tried to search for this problem but did not find any solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Check the text encoding of the page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a self-created theme, make sure to have `<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">`  inside the `<head>` tag (usually in the "header.php" file) and `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` or a similar utf-8 option in the "wp-config.php" file

Comment: Hello @Johannes 

I have tried this but it is not working either i have both of the line in the wp-config as well as in header.php still facing the same issue